# Display all mailbox calendars which a user has access to

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I would like to find out all the calendars which a user can currently access.  I searched up the Internet and the closest answer I got is this:

```
(get-mailbox) | foreach{Get-Mailboxfolderpermission (($_.PrimarySmtpAddress)+":\calendar") -user happyboy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue} |select identity, user, accessrights
```

However, the display does not really show the actual identity which is the actual mailbox which happyboy (above) has access.  The display is something like this:

```
Identity    User        AccessRights    
--------    ----        ------------    
HappyBoy    HappyBoy   {Reviewer}      
HappyBoy    HappyBoy   {LimitedDetails}
HappyBoy    HappyBoy   {Editor}        
HappyBoy    HappyBoy   {Editor}        
HappyBoy    HappyBoy   {Owner}         
HappyBoy    HappyBoy   {Editor}
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
Identity    User        AccessRights    
--------    ----        ------------    
FunnyMan    HappyBoy   {Reviewer}      
PrettyGirl  HappyBoy   {LimitedDetails}
BadBoy      HappyBoy   {Editor}        
LuckyBoy    HappyBoy   {Editor}        
SadGirl     HappyBoy   {Owner}         
LovelyGirl  HappyBoy   {Editor}
```

Can we modify the script to achieve this?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but for me the identity displayed is `HappyBoy:\Calendar`. By the way, folder names like Calendar might be affected by regional settings so you should be aware of this.

Comment: Actually, I was hoping that the script will show the Identify from Get-Mailbox but it is showing the identity of Get-MailboxFolderPermission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your one liner formatted a bit more readable:

```
(Get-Mailbox) | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Mailboxfolderpermission (($_.PrimarySmtpAddress)+":\calendar") `
        -User happyboy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    } | Select-Object Identity, User, Accessrights
```

Should make clear that the terminating pipe element (`Select-Object`) receives the output of the `Get-Mailboxfolderpermission` cmdlet, the `Get-Mailbox`output is no longer directly accessible.

This (untested) script uses the $mailbox variable to store the currently iterated mailbox.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\08\14\SO_51836373.ps1

ForEach ($mailbox in (Get-Mailbox)){
    Get-Mailboxfolderpermission (($mailbox.PrimarySmtpAddress)+":\calendar") `
        -User happyboy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Identity     = $mailbox.Identity
            User         = $_.User
            AccessRights = $_.Accessrights
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach more resembling your template stores the Mailbox identity and inserts a calculated property into the Select-Object. (also untested)

```
(Get-Mailbox) | ForEach-Object {
    $Identity = $_.Identity
    Get-Mailboxfolderpermission (($_.PrimarySmtpAddress)+":\calendar") `
        -User happyboy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    } | Select-Object @{n='Identity';e={$Identity}}, User, Accessrights
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, LotPings. the bottom script that you post works perfectly while the first script returns nothing.