# Looping Through All Calendars With Get-MailboxFolderPermission

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have researched this extensively and used much trial-and-error, but I have yet to get a scrip to work that performs the function I want it to. What I want is to create a script that will allow the user to type a username, and then run through all the mailboxes and show the user's permissions on those user's calendars. I've gotten very close with the below script, but this only works on the mailbox as a whole, and does not work if I simply add ":\Calendar" to the $Box variable. Any input on how to get this to show the calendar permissions would be welcome.

```
$Username = Read-Host "Enter the user whose access you would like to view"
foreach ($Box in Get-Mailbox) {
    Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $Box -User $Username
}
```

I know this is a repeat of a previous question, but as I've altered my code significantly, I thought it was worth asking again. Here's the link to my prior question:
[Exchange Powershell: Get-MailboxFolderPermission for all calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53559915/exchange-powershell-get-mailboxfolderpermission-for-all-calendars)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: dude just delete this question and edit your other one. You also need to give more details about the output your getting vs. what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the below code:

```
(Get-Mailbox) | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Mailboxfolderpermission (($_.PrimarySmtpAddress)+":\calendar") `
        -User happyboy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    } | Select-Object Identity, User, Accessrights
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Display all mailbox calendars which a user has access to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836373/display-all-mailbox-calendars-which-a-user-has-access-to)

Comment: It took some tweaking, but I was able to get this to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestion by @Alina-Li, I was able to work out the following code. Everything works well now:

```
(Get-Mailbox) | ForEach-Object {
        $Permission = Get-Mailboxfolderpermission ($_.PrimarySMTPAddress.Local + "@" + $_.PrimarySMTPAddress.Domain +":\calendar") `
            -User $User -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Accessrights 
        if ($Permission -ne $null) {
            echo ("Calendar: "+($_.Name))
            echo ($User+"'s Permission: "+$Permission)
            echo ""
        }
    }
```